# Problems with ajax call in component

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, model, jmodel

I am developing a joomla component.
I added a drag and drop uploader with ajax.
When a file is uploaded, a confirmation-mail should be sent.
I get the right item of the database with `$id = $app->input->getInt('id');` 
This works,
But when the ajax call is done, the variable `$id` is set to `null`, so in the email the `$customers->name` is also `null`.
Why is the complete model reloaded after the ajax-call?

**I call the controller method:**

### Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "index.php?option=com_customercenter&task=mailAfterUpload&tmpl=component",
    dataType: "json",
    formData: {"companyID":"companyID"},
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
            obj.createProgress(data[i]["name"],data[i]["path"],data[i]["size"]);
        }
    }
});
```

### Controller

```
public function mailAfterUpload() {
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $response = $model->sendEmailAfterUpload();
}
```

### Model

```
public function sendEmailAfterUpload() {
    $customers = $this->getCustomercenterData();

    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $sender = array( 
        $config->get( 'mailfrom' ),
        $config->get( 'fromname' ) 
    );

    $mailer->setSender($sender);

    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $recipient = $sender;

    $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

    $body = "Der Kunde: <b>" . $customers->name . "</b> hat neue Daten übermittelt<br>Ordner '" . $customers->upload_folder . "' checken" ;
    $subject = $customers->name . " hat neue Daten übermittelt";
    $mailer->isHTML(true);
    $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mailer->setSubject($subject);
    $mailer->setBody($body);

    $send = $mailer->Send();
    if ( $send !== true ) {
        echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->__toString();
    } else {
        echo 'Mail sent';
    }
}
```

### Model sql-query

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$id = $app->input->getInt('id');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, each http request is independent. You have to send all parameters again in each call.

Alternatively, if your client can keep session cookies, then you can store server-side variables in user session to keep an state between http requests.

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('myId', $myId);
...
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$myId = $session->get('myId');
```